# Extended MAPI -Reading mail body adds space character after every charachter

Tags: c++, outlook, exchangewebservices, mapi

I am trying to parse an email with Extended MAPI.

To get a stream pointer, I use `LPMAPIPROP::OpenProperty()` with the `PR_BODY` tag to return a `IStream*`, and I use the `IStream::Read()` method to read the data to a buffer.

For some reason, when I open the email with MFCMAPI, the body is fine. For instance, `"ABC"`.  But, when I try to read to a buffer programmatically, I get space characters after every character, eg `"A B C"`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a space (`0x20`), or is it `0x00`? If you are opening `PR_BODY_W` (as opposed to `PR_BODY_A`), you will end up with a Unicode string (two bytes per character) rather than a single-byte string.

Comment: No, it is a space 0x20, not a null terminator 0x0. I am opening `PR_BODY_W` Instaed of being 0x65 0x00 0x66 0x00 it is 0x65 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x66 0x00...

Comment: Is that what you see in MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage, select PR_BODY property, click "..." next to the "Value" edit box)?

Comment: You can also try to open PR_BODY_W in OutlookSpy - right click on the property, select IMAPIProp::OpernProperty, select IID_IStream.

Comment: I tried with OutlookSpy as well, unfortunately, the outcome is the same.

Comment: Then you are not seeing things - you really have extra spaces. Do you see the same thing in `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` (that is what Outlook actually displays)?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` was corrupted and instead of displaying RTF it just showed the `PR_BODY` with spaces between each character. I think it was caused because I tried to manually set the `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` instead of letting Outlook set it for me.

Comment: You only need to set `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` (or call `RtfSync`) if the store does not natively support RTF (`STORE_RTF_OK` bit in `PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK)`